# Fresh Install of Ubuntu 12.10 Keyboard and Mouse problem

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and when it booted up I had to press they keyboard buttons multiple times and really hard to type my password, I tried turning off the Laptop when I tried to turn it on I had to force in the power button to get it to turn on. Now the mouse is going really slowly but an external keyboard is working. 
I did not have this problem on the live install and I have had wubi on this laptop before. (now it is just Ubuntu)

I have done a complete reinstall of Ubuntu and it is the exact same, External mouse and keyboard working fine. I feel like it is the drivers.

Is there a way to reinstall the relvant drivers?

Any idea what might be causing the problem?

Is there any other information i need to post?

Comment: did you use the same dvd running live to install? possibly boot to live install again and test keyboard + mouse , or run system test

Comment: What do you mean by system test?

Comment: this is an installed test - if you're using unity type system in dash and you should find system testing. If you using gnome I believe you cna find it Applications | System tools | administration | system testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just fixed itself!!

I tried to use the windows recovery disk a few times and that kept failing. I kept reinstalling Ubuntu and it was fixed!